# clicking a button on webpage using vba

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to get a code working , but i am unable to make it click a sumbit button as the web doesnt have that button by its id, following is the html line i am trying to click, how can i click this button via vba code.

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Login" 
 name="action">Submit</button>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your code and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a reference to "Microsoft Internet Controls" which is essentially controlling Internet Explorer from VBA. If you can give me the website address I can be of more specific help, but this should get you started if it doesn't solve it for you:

```
Public Sub ButtonClicker()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim website_address As String: website_address = "YOUR ADDRESS GOES HERE"
    Dim button_name As String: button_name = "action"
    Dim button_class As String: button_class = "btn btn-default"
    Dim open_in_IE As Boolean: open_in_IE = False  'Change to True if you want to see it in action
    Dim button_collection As Object
    Dim button As Object

    On Error GoTo error_handler

    If IE Is Nothing Then Set IE = New InternetExplorer
        With IE
            .Navigate website_address

            Do While .Busy
                DoEvents
            Loop

            Do While .ReadyState <> 4
                DoEvents
            Loop

            .Visible = open_in_IE
        End With

        Set button_collection = IE.Document.getElementsByName(button_name)
            Set button = button_collection(button_class)  'Inspect Locals here to see what comes through
                button.Click
            Set button = Nothing
        Set button_collection = Nothing

        IE.Quit
        Set IE = Nothing
    Exit Sub

error_handler:
    Debug.Print "IE Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    If Not (IE Is Nothing) Then
        IE.Quit
        Set IE = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This will fail (I think) as you are passing a string to index into a collection (and that string cannot be implicitly converted) You can also combine your two Do While Loops into one and upgrade method to .Navigate2. You don't need to set objects to Nothing either as they will dereferenced when out of scope at end of sub.

Comment: See this link:
https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/88jfz0/code_help_trying_to_click_the_google_search_button/